# Como fazer o auto incremento no MySQL sem declarar as colunas no INSERT?

Tags: mysql, sql, sintaxe

Eu reparei que quando eu tenho uma coluna com `auto_increment`, eu tenho que declarar as colunas no `INSERT`.

Por exemplo, eu criei essa tabela de teste:

```
create table teste(
id int auto_increment,
nome varchar(100) not null,
valor decimal(5,2),
constraint id_pk primary key (id));
```

Eu queria conseguir inserir os dados sem declarar as colunas, como nesse exemplo:

```
insert into teste values ('Danilo',333.33)
```

Porém ele não entende, e no fim eu tenho que declarar assim:

```
insert into teste (nome,valor) values ('Danilo',333.33)
```

Minha dúvida é se tem como eu fazer um `INSERT` sem declarar todas as colunas, tipo usar alguma palavra reservada ou algo do tipo que o MySQL compreenda.

Comment: Se você estiver adicionando valores para todas as colunas da tabela, você não precisa especificar os nomes das colunas na consulta. No entanto, certifique-se a ordem dos valores está na mesma ordem que as colunas na tabela.

Comment: insert into teste values ('','Danilo',333.33)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como está usando uma sintaxe posicional com todas as colunas tem que mandar valores para todas elas. E como não quer mandar para a primeira coluna, mande um nulo. Já que ela tem um valor padrão automático esse valor será colocado no lugar do nulo.

```
insert into teste values (null, 'Danilo',333.33)
```

Veja [funcionando no **SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63bfe6). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Insert/AutoIncrement.sql).

Se achar ruim aí a saída é a que já achou, usar a sintaxe de argumentos nomeados para não considerar a posição de cada coluna.

Comment: Você tem que responder perguntas mais difíceis,  esses ticos-ticos tem que deixar pra nós rs!