# Insert no banco de dados no C#

Tags: c#, sql

Sou iniciante na área e preciso fazer um `select` em duas tabelas do banco SQL server através do C#, como mostra abaixo:

```
("INSERT INTO entrada_2(id_entrada, id_saida, descricao_entrada, data, valor_entrada)" +
    "VALUES('" + Cb_Descricao_Entrada.Text + "', '" + hoje.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "', '" + Txb_Valor_Entrada.Text.Replace(",", ".") + "')", conexao);
```

Minhas tabelas:

```
entradas

id_entrada               int pk       not null
id_saida                 int fk      not null
descricao_entrada        varchar(150) not null
data                     datetime     not null
valor_entrada            varchar(20)  not null
```

```
saidas

id_saida                 int pk       not null
descricao_saida          varchar(150) not null
data                     datetime     not null
valor_saida              varchar(20)  not null
```

Quando executo o `insert` apresenta erro e nao deixa fazer o `insert` e diz que as colunas são desiguais.

Agradeço desde já quem puder me ajudar. Obrigado

Comment: Apenas conte a quantidade de campos que colocou  entre parênteses após o nome da tabela (`entrada_2`) [5] e a quantidade de valores que você colocou na cláusula VALUES [3]. As quantidades precisam ser iguais.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Minha duvida é minha tabela tem [5] itens para inserir, destes [5] um é pk e o outro fk, como faço para referencia - los no form da minha aplicação? ocultá-los no insert  da erro, e coloca-los também!

Comment: Se na definição de sua tabela a PK tiver especificado um valor default então você pode omitir tanto o nome do campo quanto o valor, se não tiver um valor default então é obrigatório você informar um valor. Quanto a FK você tem que informar a qual registro da tabela referenciada esta linha sendo incluída esta relacionada e portanto é obrigatório especificar um valor, sua aplicação é que tem que saber qual valor informar, lembrando que o registro correspondente já deve existir na tabela relacionada.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Vlw

Comment: Seu modelo está errado porque do jeito que está aí, você precisa ter saídas antes de entradas.

Answer (score 0):

O insert da sua tabela deve contemplar os campos da mesma.

Se o Id, for auto-incremente, só deixe o espaço referente a ele.
Veja essa questão que aborda isso aqui: [Questão do Auto-increment](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/318632/como-fazer-o-auto-incremento-no-mysql-sem-declarar-as-colunas-no-insert)

Outro ponto, seu FK, deverá já existir. Se tiver dúvidas sobre FK veja: [Pergunta sobre FK](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/335489/sql-como-fa%C3%A7o-um-insert-into-em-uma-tabela-que-tem-fk)

Caso sua ideia de Fk, seja preencher o saída após o entrada. Recomendo inverter seu FK, e referenciar o id_Entrada, na tabela de saída.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Vlw

Comment: Se a resposta respondeu a questão, marque-a como resposta certa.